# Setting a cookie's domain in jQuery dynamically

Tags: java, jquery, cookies, jstl, el

I have a fairly standard Spring/Hibernate Java project where I need to set a cookie based on the domain of the environment I'm in(Local, Test and Prod).

```
$.cookie("[cookie_name]", "[cookie_data]", { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: '', secure: false });
```

Is there a JSP/JSTL tag or a way in expression language to determine the domain the servlet container is running on?  Or is there a similar method in javascript/jQuery?

For instance, if I am running the app on a Tomcat Server on test, I want the IP of the test server or if I am running on production I want the domain name of the prod site.

I am looking for something along the lines of ${applicationScope.domain}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Protocol: ${pageContext.request.protocol}
- Remote Address: ${pageContext.request.remoteAddr}
- Remote Host: ${pageContext.request.remoteHost}
- Remote Port: ${pageContext.request.remotePort}
- Scheme:${pageContext.request.scheme}
- Secure: ${pageContext.request.secure}
- Local Address: ${pageContext.request.localAddr}
- Local Name: ${pageContext.request.localName}
- Local Port: ${pageContext.request.localPort}
- Server Name: ${pageContext.request.serverName}
- Server Port: ${pageContext.request.serverPort}

source:

http://www.steve-farmer.com/examples/el/ui/req-server.jsp
http://www.steve-farmer.com/examples/el/ui/req-misc.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try: `${pageContext.request.localName}`